# Storing data to retrieve it based upon the hour

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble laying out how to do this. What I am trying to accomplish is this:

I have data being inserted, and I want to pull statistics on the data using PHP - how many were inserted in the last hour (hour 15).. There's going to be a lot of records 1 million +. When I insert this data, should each new data insert have a column with date time?

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: 15 million inserted per hour? or 15 million total?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using logging for the stats.  You could maintain a counter in memory and log every 1000 rows entered (or whatever number is meaningful to you).

Answer (score 0):

add a datetime column to your structure, filling it in with "NOW()"on every insert.  as long as you have an index, simple queries should run very efficiently.